# TinyThread counter - portable c++0 and c++11 inter thread communication made simple

Tags: c++, multithreading

I saw this example as part of the TinyThread c++ library and noticed how it is incrementing gCount on a secondary thread, and then being printed by the main thread. See test 5

```
/* -*- mode: c++; tab-width: 2; indent-tabs-mode: nil; -*-
Copyright (c) 2010-2012 Marcus Geelnard

This software is provided 'as-is', without any express or implied
warranty. In no event will the authors be held liable for any damages
arising from the use of this software.

Permission is granted to anyone to use this software for any purpose,
including commercial applications, and to alter it and redistribute it
freely, subject to the following restrictions:

    1. The origin of this software must not be misrepresented; you must not
    claim that you wrote the original software. If you use this software
    in a product, an acknowledgment in the product documentation would be
    appreciated but is not required.

    2. Altered source versions must be plainly marked as such, and must not be
    misrepresented as being the original software.

    3. This notice may not be removed or altered from any source
    distribution.
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <tinythread.h>
#include <fast_mutex.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace tthread;

// HACK: Mac OS X and early MinGW do not support thread-local storage
#if defined(__APPLE__) || (defined(__MINGW32__) && (__GNUC__ < 4))
 #define NO_TLS
#endif


// Thread local storage variable
#ifndef NO_TLS
thread_local int gLocalVar;
#endif

// Mutex + global count variable
mutex gMutex;
fast_mutex gFastMutex;
int gCount;

// Condition variable
condition_variable gCond;

// Thread function: Thread ID
void ThreadIDs(void * aArg)
{
  cout << " My thread id is " << this_thread::get_id() << "." << endl;
}

#ifndef NO_TLS
// Thread function: Thread-local storage
void ThreadTLS(void * aArg)
{
  gLocalVar = 2;
  cout << " My gLocalVar is " << gLocalVar << "." << endl;
}
#endif

// Thread function: Mutex locking
void ThreadLock(void * aArg)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 10000; ++ i)
  {
    lock_guard<mutex> lock(gMutex);
    ++ gCount;
  }
}

// Thread function: Mutex locking
void ThreadLock2(void * aArg)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 10000; ++ i)
  {
    lock_guard<fast_mutex> lock(gFastMutex);
    ++ gCount;
  }
}

// Thread function: Condition notifier
void ThreadCondition1(void * aArg)
{
  lock_guard<mutex> lock(gMutex);
  -- gCount;
  gCond.notify_all();
}

// Thread function: Condition waiter
void ThreadCondition2(void * aArg)
{
  cout << " Wating..." << flush;
  lock_guard<mutex> lock(gMutex);
  while(gCount > 0)
  {
    cout << "." << flush;
    gCond.wait(gMutex);
  }
  cout << "." << endl;
}

// Thread function: Yield
void ThreadYield(void * aArg)
{
  // Yield...
  this_thread::yield();
}

// Thread function: Detach
void ThreadDetach(void * aArg)
{
  // We don't do anything much, just sleep a little...
  this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100));
}


// This is the main program (i.e. the main thread)
int main()
{
  // Test 1: Show number of CPU cores in the system
  cout << "PART I: Info" << endl;
  cout << " Number of processor cores: " << thread::hardware_concurrency() << endl;

  // Test 2: thread IDs
  cout << endl << "PART II: Thread IDs" << endl;
  {
    // Show the main thread ID
    cout << " Main thread id is " << this_thread::get_id() << "." << endl;

    // Start a bunch of child threads - only run a single thread at a time
    thread t1(ThreadIDs, 0);
    t1.join();
    thread t2(ThreadIDs, 0);
    t2.join();
    thread t3(ThreadIDs, 0);
    t3.join();
    thread t4(ThreadIDs, 0);
    t4.join();
  }

  // Test 3: thread local storage
  cout << endl << "PART III: Thread local storage" << endl;
#ifndef NO_TLS
  {
    // Clear the TLS variable (it should keep this value after all threads are
    // finished).
    gLocalVar = 1;
    cout << " Main gLocalVar is " << gLocalVar << "." << endl;

    // Start a child thread that modifies gLocalVar
    thread t1(ThreadTLS, 0);
    t1.join();

    // Check if the TLS variable has changed
    if(gLocalVar == 1)
      cout << " Main gLocalID was not changed by the child thread - OK!" << endl;
    else
      cout << " Main gLocalID was changed by the child thread - FAIL!" << endl;
  }
#else
  cout << " TLS is not supported on this platform..." << endl;
#endif

  // Test 4: mutex locking
  cout << endl << "PART IV: Mutex locking (100 threads x 10000 iterations)" << endl;
  {
    // Clear the global counter.
    gCount = 0;

    // Start a bunch of child threads
    list<thread *> threadList;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++ i)
      threadList.push_back(new thread(ThreadLock, 0));

    // Wait for the threads to finish
    list<thread *>::iterator it;
    for(it = threadList.begin(); it != threadList.end(); ++ it)
    {
      thread * t = *it;
      t->join();
      delete t;
    }

    // Check the global count
    cout << " gCount = " << gCount << endl;
  }

  // Test 5: fast_mutex locking
  cout << endl << "PART V: Fast mutex locking (100 threads x 10000 iterations)" << endl;
  {
    // Clear the global counter.
    gCount = 0;

    // Start a bunch of child threads
    list<thread *> threadList;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++ i)
      threadList.push_back(new thread(ThreadLock2, 0));

    // Wait for the threads to finish
    list<thread *>::iterator it;
    for(it = threadList.begin(); it != threadList.end(); ++ it)
    {
      thread * t = *it;
      t->join();
      delete t;
    }

    // Check the global count
    cout << " gCount = " << gCount << endl;
  }

  // Test 6: condition variable
  cout << endl << "PART VI: Condition variable (40 + 1 threads)" << endl;
  {
    // Set the global counter to the number of threads to run.
    gCount = 40;

    // Start the waiting thread (it will wait for gCount to reach zero).
    thread t1(ThreadCondition2, 0);

    // Start a bunch of child threads (these will decrease gCount by 1 when they
    // finish)
    list<thread *> threadList;
    for(int i = 0; i < 40; ++ i)
      threadList.push_back(new thread(ThreadCondition1, 0));

    // Wait for the waiting thread to finish
    t1.join();

    // Wait for the other threads to finish
    list<thread *>::iterator it;
    for(it = threadList.begin(); it != threadList.end(); ++ it)
    {
      thread * t = *it;
      t->join();
      delete t;
    }
  }

  // Test 7: yield
  cout << endl << "PART VII: Yield (40 + 1 threads)" << endl;
  {
    // Start a bunch of child threads
    list<thread *> threadList;
    for(int i = 0; i < 40; ++ i)
      threadList.push_back(new thread(ThreadYield, 0));

    // Yield...
    this_thread::yield();

    // Wait for the threads to finish
    list<thread *>::iterator it;
    for(it = threadList.begin(); it != threadList.end(); ++ it)
    {
      thread * t = *it;
      t->join();
      delete t;
    }
  }

  // Test 8: sleep
  cout << endl << "PART VIII: Sleep (10 x 100 ms)" << endl;
  {
    // Sleep...
    cout << " Sleeping" << flush;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++ i)
    {
      this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100));
      cout << "." << flush;
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  // Test 9: detach
  cout << endl << "PART IX: Detach" << endl;
  {
    thread t(ThreadDetach, 0);
    t.detach();
    cout << " Detached from thread." << endl;
  }
}
```

So I tried to make my own code, but not only does the main thread not see the variable increment, but when I added sleep to the worker thread it no longer tries to print the variable on the main thread. Because of these two problems the worker thread never quits either.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include "tinythread.h"
#include "fast_mutex.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace tthread;

fast_mutex workerThreadMutex;
bool killThread = false;
int number = 0;
void workerThread(void * aArg)
{
  bool running = true;
  int number = 0;
  while(running)
  {
     lock_guard<fast_mutex> lock(workerThreadMutex);
     number++;
     cout << "secondThread::" << number << endl;
     this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000));
     if(killThread)
        running =true;
  }
}
int main()
{
    thread* wThread = new thread(workerThread, 0);
    bool running = true;
    while(running)
    {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100));
        if(workerThreadMutex.try_lock())
        {
            cout << "mainThread::" << number << endl;
            if(number == 100)
            {
                killThread = true;
                running = false;
            }
            workerThreadMutex.unlock();
        }
    }
    wThread->join();
    delete wThread;
    return 0;
}
```

Can you help?

edit: made a change to my code

edit: fixed local variable issue, it works now, except for the kill thread boolean is not being detected so the secondary thread (worker thread) is not exiting.

edit: fixed issue with local variable

edit: fixed issue with sleep

edit: fixed issue killThread

edit: all problems fixed

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include "tinythread.h"
#include "fast_mutex.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace tthread;

fast_mutex workerThreadMutex;
bool killThread = false;
int number = 0;
  bool running = true;
void workerThread(void * aArg)
{
  while(running)
  {
    {
     lock_guard<fast_mutex> lock(workerThreadMutex);
     number++;
     if(killThread)
        running =false;
     }
     this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(50));
  }
}
int main()
{
    thread* wThread = new thread(workerThread, 0);
    while(running)
    {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100));
        if(workerThreadMutex.try_lock())
        {
            cout << "mainThread::" << number << endl;
            if(number > 100)
            {
                killThread = true;
                //running = false;
            }
            workerThreadMutex.unlock();
        }
    }
    wThread->join();
    delete wThread;
    return 0;
}
```

edit: further modification to show portable c++11 friendly inter thread communication

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include "tinythread.h"
#include "fast_mutex.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace tthread;

fast_mutex workerThreadMutex;
bool killThread = false;
int number = 0;
bool running = true;
string message = "";
void workerThread(void * aArg)
{
    while(running)
    {
        {
            lock_guard<fast_mutex> lock(workerThreadMutex);
            if(message=="")
            {
                number++;
                ostringstream Convert;
                Convert << number; 
                message = Convert.str();
            }
            if(killThread)
                running =false;
        }
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1));
    }
}
int main()
{
    thread* wThread = new thread(workerThread, 0);
    bool stopMainThreadLoop = false;
    while(!stopMainThreadLoop)
    {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10));
        if(workerThreadMutex.try_lock())
        {
            //cout << "mainThread::" << number << endl;
            cout << "mainThread::" << message << endl;
            //if(number > 100)
            if(message == "100")
            {
                killThread = true;
                stopMainThreadLoop = true;
            }
            message = "";
            workerThreadMutex.unlock();
        }
    }
    wThread->join();
    delete wThread;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you think that somebody is going to wade through all that code. Perhaps narrow it down a bit. Also is it wise to post copyrighted code?

Comment: Permission is granted to anyone to use this software for any purpose,
including commercial applications, and to alter it and redistribute it
freely, subject to the following restrictions:

Comment: I am looking for someone familiar with tiny thread not you.

Comment: Are you sure this library is still useful since C++11 introduced standard multi-threading tools?

Comment: Please check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons as stuff on this site falls under that. What takes precedence is hard to tell unless you are a lawyer

Comment: The TinyThread library says its c++11 friendly and c++0 friendly

Comment: 4386427 noticed a bug with a local variable. I have fixed that, and it works now except for the killThread boolean not being detected. so the mainthread is now sat waiting for the worker thread to finish. Can anybody see the problem with that?

Comment: @Chris `if(killThread)
        running =true;
     }` ??

Comment: @Chris - I'm not sure it is a good idea to edit/fix the code from the original question. Now new readers can't see the problem anymore. Maybe it would have been better to keep the original code as it was and then add the fixed code in a new code section below the original.

Comment: good Idea, I will put the old code back in there before the fixed code

Comment: also added proof that portable c++0 and c++11 inter thread communication can be simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this part of your code

```
int number = 0;  // Global variable, i.e. will be used by main
void workerThread(void * aArg)
{
  bool running = true;
  int number = 0; // Local variable, i.e. will be used by in the function
```

So `main`is using one variable and the function (aka the thread) is using another. Consequently main can't see any increments.

Just remove the local variable.

**For the sleep part**

I think the problem is that you do the sleep while holding the mutex.

Try this:

```
void workerThread(void * aArg)
{
  bool running = true;
  //----------------------  int number = 0;
  while(running)
  {
     {
         lock_guard<fast_mutex> lock(workerThreadMutex);
         number++;
         //cout << "secondThread::" << number << endl;

         if(killThread)
            running =true;
     }
     this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000));
  }
}
```

**For the kill:**

Try this

```
       if(number >= 100)    // Changed
        {
            killThread = true;
            running = false;
        }
```

Inside the function

```
 if(killThread)
    running =true;  // Should be false
```

Comment: so how did it work with gCount, if you can tell me that I will accept your answer

Comment: `gCount` was not declared both local and global - as far as I can see

Comment: ok its working now, except for the boolean killthread, can you see whats wrong?

Comment: ok I have fixed that too. Thanks again, by the way, do you think this will have a chance to create a race condition?

Comment: @Chris - where do expect/fear a race? I can't spot any

Comment: great :) I just heard that mutex can create race conditions, something I'm not fully understanding yet, but if you can't see one, it's possible it's simple enough not to have one.

Comment: @Chris - a race condition is when multiple threads access (aka read or write) the same data at the same time. For instance changes made by one thread maybe overwritten by another. A mutes is what you can use to avoid races, i.e. only the thread holding the mutex may access the data.